# Mule ESB and Alfresco Web Services CreateFolder. MIME Issue

Tags: web-services, soap, mule, alfresco, mule-studio

I am trying to create a folder in Alfresco using Mule ESB and Alfresco WS.

I am getting an error complaining about it a MIME issue. the flows is as below:

```
<flow name="MuleProxyFlowWS" doc:name="MuleProxyFlowWS">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="localhost" port="8088" path="createCase" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <cxf:jaxws-service namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/ws/200908/"
        service="com.alfresco.cmis.ws.ObjectService" doc:name="SOAP"
        enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" mtomEnabled="true"
        serviceClass="com.alfresco.cmis.ws.ObjectServicePort">
        <cxf:ws-security>
            <cxf:ws-config>
                <cxf:property key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                <cxf:property key="username" value="admin" />
                <cxf:property key="passwordCallbackClass" value="mule.security.PasswordCallback" />
            </cxf:ws-config>
        </cxf:ws-security>
    </cxf:jaxws-service>
    <cxf:jaxws-client doc:name="SOAP"
        clientClass="com.alfresco.cmis.ws.ObjectService" operation="createFolder"
        port="ObjectServicePort"
        wsdlLocation="/home/dev/MuleStudio/workspace/soapws/src/main/resources/cmis_ws.wsdl"
        enableMuleSoapHeaders="false">
        <cxf:ws-security>
            <cxf:ws-config>
                <cxf:property key="user" value="admin" />
                <cxf:property key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                <cxf:property key="passwordCallbackClass" value="mule.security.PasswordCallback" />
            </cxf:ws-config>
        </cxf:ws-security>
    </cxf:jaxws-client>
    <logger
        message="***** COMES HERE WEB SERVICE END POINT ****** #[payload:java.lang.String]"
        level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
```

The Error:

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Couldn't find MIME boundary: ------=_Part_225_1899798280.1399630782102. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: PushbackInputStream</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using the old WebServices stuff? [CMIS](http://cmis.alfresco.com/) is the recommended way to create/update/version/store/browser/etc documents

Comment: According to com.alfresco.cmis.ws.ObjectService" operation="createFolder, it's def the CMIS WS variant :)

Comment: I don't really get what the body is you're sending to Alfresco. A createFolder request needs repositoryID, properties & root folder ID. I guess you should play with the CMIS workbench and select the WS implementation.

Comment: Yes I am aware of CMIS but wanted to have both options available. Using SoapUI I am able to send a request but for some reasons I am unable to do it via Mule. So the request is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Set `Content-Type` property before calling `jaxws:client` like:

```
 <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="whatever it is" />
```

For xml, it is `application/xml`